# Appending variables to hash keys

Tags: string, thymeleaf

Is there a possible to use `#` in Thymeleaf attributes?

I need to set the attribute `data-target` where the value starts with a hash key.

So, finally it should look like `data-target=#1234`. The problem here is, that the `1234` comes from the database and should be set via Thymeleaf.

I tried `th:attr = "'data-target = #' + ${affiliate.identificationCode}"` but this will throw an error: *Could not parse as assignation sequence: "'data-target = #' + ${affiliate.identificationCode}"*.

How can I append variables to an hash?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to place the '#' within ${}

like `th:attr="data-target=${'#' + affiliate.identificationCode}"`